# What are good ways to create real-time stats for high-load webservers?

Tags: statistics, monitoring

Say I have a bunch of webservers each serving 100's of requests/s, and I want to see real time stats like:

- Request rate over last 5s, 60s, 5 min etc
- Number of unique users seen again per time window

Or in general for a bunch of timestamped events, I want to see real-time derived statistics - what's the best way to go about it?

I've considered having each GET request update a global counter somewhere, then sampling that at various intervals, but at the event rates I'm seeing it's hard to get a distributed counter that's fast enough.

Any ideas welcome!

Added: Servers are Linux running Apache/mod_wsgi, with a Python (Django) stack.
Added: To give a sense of the event rates I want to track stats for, they're coming in at over 10K events/s. Even incrementing a distributed counter at that rate is a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to help us try out the beta of our agent for application performance monitoring in Python web applications.

http://newrelic.com

It delves more into the application performance rather than just the web server, but since any bottlenecks aren't generate going to be the web server, but your application then that is going to be more useful anyway.

Disclaimer. I work for New Relic and this is the project I am working on. It is a paid product, but the beta means it is free for now with all features. Later when that changes, if you didn't want to pay for it, their is still a Lite subscription level which is free and which gives you basic web metrics reporting which still covers some of what you are after. Anyway, right now would be a great opportunity to make use of it to debug your performance while you can.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting your answer as we tried newrelic and although it wasn't exactly what we wanted, it seems to be a decent tool that does what the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all good servers provide this kind of functionality out of the box. For example, Apache has the mod_status module and Glassfish supports JMX. Furthermore, there are many commercial packages for monitoring clusters, such as Hyperic and Zenoss.

What web or application server are you using? It is difficult to provide a solution without that information.

Comment: It's more monitoring and collating the business level metrics such as unique users (AFAIK, Apache can't do that) or other arbitrary events. Most of the cluster monitors I've looked at would struggle at a rate of 10K events/s which is what I'm dealing with

Answer (score 1):

Look at using WebSockets, their overhead is much smaller than a HTTP request, they are very well suited to real-time web applications. See: http://nodeknockout.com/ for Node based websocket examples.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

You will need to run a daemon if you want to run it on your apache server.

Also take a look at:
http://kaazing.com/ if you wan't less hassle, but are willing to fork out some cash.

[image: http://websocket.org/img/poll-ws-compare.gif]

Comment: Don't see how WebSockets helps with this. The issue isn't that I can't handle 10K req/s (I can), but that *monitoring* what's happening at that scale is a challenge

Comment: @Malcolm i'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but... if you use Node.js (an event driven platform, all code is asynchronous) you can keep track of all of these requests in realtime, and store them when required.

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows side, [Perfmonance monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115.aspx) is the tool you should investigate.

As [Jared O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336409/what-are-good-ways-to-create-real-time-stats-for-high-load-webservers/#7359696) said, you should precise what kind of web server you want to monitor.